# invalid assignment operator Error on add , subtract, divide, multiply signs

Tags: java, string, math, operator-keyword

I am getting the invalid assignment error when trying to parse two strings and them perform mathematical operations on them :S

the error is in this line,

```
                   IfirstValue+IfirstValue;
```

Here is the complete code,

```
firstValue = 34;
    secondValue = 10;

     IfirstValue = Integer.parseInt(firstValue);
               IsecondValue = Integer.parseInt(secondValue);

                   if (operator == 3){
                       IfirstValue+IfirstValue;
                   }
```

I tried replacing '+' by '-' , '/' , '*' but the error remains same :S

(operator is input from the user)

please explain why it is happening.

Comment: please give the entire compilation error.

Comment: Please show a short but complete example - you haven't even shown us the type of `IfirstValue`. Formatting your code would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't assign the result of the expression. Try:

```
IfirstValue = IfirstValue+IfirstValue;
```

or

```
IfirstValue += IfirstValue;
```

Also, please avoid starting variable names with capital letters, it violates Java's coding convention.